# How to specify function signature for function handles in MATLAB code generation?

Tags: matlab, pointers, polymorphism, matlab-coder, function-handle

I want to compile a MEX from a function that has the following code (`MATLAB R2015a`):

```
function r = MyFunc(x,type)
    ind = randi(numel(x), 1);
    getInd = @getIndFixed;
    if strcmpi(type, 'random')
        ind = numel(x);
        getInd = @getIndRandom; % error here
    end
    x(getInd(ind)) = 1;
end
function k = getIndFixed(n)
    k = n;
end
function k = getIndRandom(n)
    k = randi(n, 1);
end
```

I get the `type mismatch` error between `getIndFixed` and `getIndRandom` at the line specified above:

> Type mismatch: function_handle getIndFixed ~= getIndRandom.

- Is there a way around this problem?
- For instance, a way to specify that both functions have the same signature?

In C, the signature of the function would be:

```
int (*getInd)(int);
int getIndFixed(int);
int getIndRandom(int);
//...
getInd = getIndFixed;
getInd = getIndRandom;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change function handles to different functions after they are assigned in code generation. Unlike "C" these function calls are resolved at compile time. If your `type` input is constant then you can write your code as

```
function r = MyFunc(x,type)
    if strcmpi(type, 'random')
        ind = numel(x);
        getInd = @getIndRandom; % error here
    else
        ind = randi(numel(x), 1);
        getInd = @getIndFixed;
    end
    x(getInd(ind)) = 1;
end
```

If `type` is not constant you need to move everything inside if or else branch.